# Multiply and divide

Tags: american-english

I’ve been always wondering, when speaking and you have to say 2 times less, I mean:
We use: double to express something multiplied by 2
We use:triple … multiplied by 3
But how do you express when a thing is divided by 2?
Should I use half?
What when it’s divided by 3?
One third?

Answer (score 1):

The verb form of "to cut into half" is *halve*, so you could say, e.g.:

> *The estate was halved*.

if it was split into two equal (or roughly equal) parts.

There may be a verb for "divided into thirds," but if there is, I can't think of it, and I don't think it's a common one. I'd probably say:

> *The pizza was divided into thirds*.

Comment: Please unaccept my answer and wait a day or so. There might be a verb for "cut into thirds" and I may be unaware of it. It's considered good practice to wait at least half a day to give others a crack at the question, and you're less likely to get more helpful answers if you accept an answer too soon. I've even seen a few cases where an answer was blatently wrong but the O.P. accepted it before others had a chance to review it and comment on it – that's even worse! I don't think I've said anything wrong here, but I'd much rather give others time to verify that. English varies around the globe.

Answer (score 1):

**Halve** means "divide by two" or "divide into two parts".  **Bisect** also means "divide into two parts"; it is mostly used for geometry problems.

**Trisect** means "divide into three parts".

**Quarter** means "divide by four" or "divide into four parts".

**Tithe** means "a tenth of" or "[give a tenth of the net increase of](http://www.nauvootimes.com/cgi-bin/nauvoo_column.pl?author=orson-scott-card#.VFZPkKG1mgY)".  **Decimate** means "kill a tenth of".

Comment: Trisect is a word used almost exclusively in a mathematical or geometric sense, more so even than bisect. It would be unusual to see it in common language.  "Divided/cut/separated into thirds" or "divided/cut/separated into three {nouns}" would be far more likely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common usage, but OED has this definition...

> **third** (verb, transitive, defn 1)
>    *To divide (anything) into three equal parts; to reduce to one third of the number or bulk.*

In fact, it's *so* uncommon it's probably a bad idea to use it at all with that sense. All native speakers would understand the intended meaning *in context*, but most would probably think it "ungrammatical". To the extent that ***to third*** is used as a verb at all, it's usually in the sense of OED's next definition...

> **third** (defn 2)
>    *To speak in favour of (a motion, proposition, etc.) as third speaker; to support the [seconder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/seconder).*

But it's worth noting that even the above is sufficiently rare that [this speaker](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qghLAAAAYAAJ&q=%22I%20third%20the%20motion%22&dq=%22I%20third%20the%20motion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jEhWVMHPAueM7Abr8oAQ&redir_esc=y) gets a laugh for using it, and in the written form, ***"third"*** is placed in [scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) to acknowledge an unusual / non-standard usage.

---

> *There are two of us, so I'll **halve** the cake*　　　　　　　　(we get [a] ***half*** each)
>    ??*There are three of us, so I'll **third** the cake* 　　　　　　(we get a ***third*** each)
>    *There are three of us, so I'll **cut the cake into three***　　 (far more likely)
>    *There are four of us, so I'll **quarter** the cake* 　　　　　　(we get a ***quarter*** each)

I don't think there are any valid verb forms beyond ***quarter*** = divide into four parts.

Comment: Its interesting how "a quarter" sounds better than "a third", maybe because i didnt hear it much. Even tough the same "pattern" apply for: quarter or half, a third doesnt just sound that good.

Comment: @Alpha2k: I don't think any native speakers would see anything remotely unusual about the *noun* form ***a third***. I assume the reason we think the *verb* form sounds odd is because we rarely hear it. Mainly because dividing things into three happens less often than dividing into two or four parts, but perhaps also because a long time ago people might have used the now-obsolete ***tripart*** where they needed a verb form.